# Removing submodule status for many subfolders to commit one large repository to Github

Tags: github, git-submodules

I have a folder stored locally which contains many, many subfolders all of which are/were their own repositories. It's all of the lectures, exercises, etc. from school - when I graduated and had to return my school laptop, before my school Gitlab account was shut down, I simply copied the root folder onto a flash drive and then transferred it to my personal computer, planning to add them to my Github later. In retrospect I realize this was not the best way to go about it; I was in a rush (we were given explicit permission to keep copies of everything by the way).

Right now I have this massive folder called "LecturesExercisesEtc" which I've init/commit/push'd to a new private repository on Github, but Git recognizes each folder it contains as repositories (many of which themselves contain repositories) so essentially the root repository is currently just a handful of empty folders on Github.

I just want these on my Github for record keeping and safe storage; I don't care about previous commit history for the individual projects (the important ones I've already extracted out into their own separate repositories). **Is there any way to tell git to ignore nested repositories/submodule status and push all contents to the root repository, without having to go through and manually delete git files for hundreds of lectures and exercises?**

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the `absorbgitdirs` command for [git-submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), but I don’t think it does exactly what you asked for. If I understand your question, it sounds like you want to collapse all the nested repositories; `absorbgitdirs` keeps them as separate repositories, and just moves them all to the top-level `.git` directory.

The simplest solution might be to script your way through removing the `.git` directories for the nested repositories, rather than trying to do something clever with Git.

```
find * -type d -name ‘.git’ -exec mv -i “{}” “{}_old” \;
```

By default, `*` shouldn’t match hidden directories like `.git`, which should keep it from renaming the top-level `.git` directory.
Then you could just add everything, but ignore the `.git` directories by
Then add “.git_old” to the `.gitignore` file, and use `git add .` to add everything to the top-level repository.